# Forbidden Attributes Error when assigning nested attributes in Rails 4 using Postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

An AssessmentItem has many ItemLevels and one ItemLevel belongs to an AssessmentItem. 
In my model I have

```
has_many :item_levels
accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_levels
```

When updating an Item, you should be able to specify what levels should be associated with that Item. The update action should receive the parameters specified for levels and create new ItemLevel objects that are associated with the Item being updated, and delete any levels that we previously associated and not specified when updating. However, when I try to create new levels, I get an `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes` error.

Controller:

```
 def update
            @item = AssessmentItem.find(params[:id])
            old_levels = @item.item_levels    #active record collection
            @item.update_attributes(update_params)
            convert_levels = old_levels.map {|l| l.attributes} #puts into array       
            (items - convert_levels).each{|l| ItemLevel.create(l)} ##causes error
            (convert_levels - level_params).each { |l| ItemLevel.find(l["id"]).destroy }
          end
        end

        private
        def level_params
          params.require(:assessment_item).permit(:item_levels => [:descriptor, :level])
        end

        def update_params
          params.require(:assessment_item).permit(:slug, :description, :name)
        end
```

This is my json request in Postman:

```
{
    "assessment_item": {
        "slug" : "newSlug",
        "description" : "NewDescriptiong",
        "name" : "different name",
        "item_level_attributes":[
            {            
                "descriptor":"this should be new",
                "level":"excellent"
            }
            ]}
}
```

How can I get my action to allow the parameters? How can I effectively pass them to the factory? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also permit `item_level_attributes` in `update_params` like this:

```
def update_params
    params.require(:assessment_item).permit(:slug, :description, :name, :item_levels => [:descriptor, :level])
end
```

or

```
def update_params
    params.require(:assessment_item).permit(:slug, :description, :name, :item_level_attributes => [:descriptor, :level])
end
```